# How to plot a tree in Python with node labels?

Tags: python, plot, tree

I would like to reproduce the following figure using any tool in Python:

[image: A tree with node labels]

(This is a part of figure 5 page 75 in [^Furnival1974] that I created using Inkscape).

I would like not only to reproduce this tree, but other trees using Python programming.
Using [ETE](http://etetoolkit.org/), I wrote this:

```py
from ete3 import Tree

t = Tree("(12345, (1234, (1235, (123)), (1245, (124, 125, (12))), (1345, (134, (135, (13))), 145), 2345));")
t.show()
```

which produces:

[image: A tree with ETE]

The fact that the tree is horizontal is not the issue. Another issue is that I was not able to set the labels : the input argument is a string and a single character string cannot define both the node and its label. The main problem for me is that the nodes have no labels. The tool seems to know only leafs, while my need is to have labels on nodes. How can I create the required tree using Python?

[^Furnival1974]: Furnival, G. M., & Wilson, R. W. (1974). Regression by leaps and bounds. Technometrics. 16:499-511.

Comment: Have you tried the example from http://etetoolkit.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial_drawing.html#show-leaf-node-names-branch-length-and-branch-support

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I just tried: it adds labels to the branches, but does not change the labels of the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Your two graphs don't match. I'll be trying to reproduce the first one though, by using the Python interface of [graphviz](/questions/tagged/graphviz). So, assuming you have a string as an input :

```
s = """(
    12345,
        (1234, 1235, (123,),
        1245, (124, 125, (12,)),
        1345, (134, 135, (13,), 145),
        2345
        )
    )"""
```

And a mapping for the nodes and their labels :

```
nodes = {
    "12345": "588", "1234": "592", "1235": "596", "1245": "596", "1345": "605",
    "2345": "660", "123": "597", "124": "615", "125": "597", "134": "612",
    "135": "618", "145": "618", "12": "615", "13": "641"
}
```

---

You can try something like below :

```
#pip install graphviz
from graphviz import Digraph
from ast import literal_eval
from itertools import chain, product

def edgewise(obj):
    def istup(item):
        return isinstance(item, tuple)
    for p,t in zip(obj, obj[1:]):
        if not istup(p) and istup(t):
            yield product(
                [str(p)], (str(i) for i in t if not istup(i))
            )
        if istup(t):
            yield from edgewise(t)

edges = chain.from_iterable(edgewise(literal_eval(s)))

config = {
    "graph_attr": {"size": "5!"},
    "node_attr": {"shape": "plain", "fontsize": "18", "fontname": "Times-Roman"},
    "edge_attr": {"dir": "none", "penwidth": "2"}
}

dot = Digraph(**config)

for n, l in nodes.items():
    dot.node(name=n, label=rf"{n}\n({l})")

for e in edges:
    dot.edge(*e)

# dot.render(filename="output", format="pdf", view=True) # to make a pdf, image..
```

Output :

[image]